# TClientDataSet faulted with message

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

got a small situation here, I haven't used TClientDataSet until recently(it requires midas.dll) so now I'm facing a very awkward error, not very descriptive:

### Debugger Fault Notification

Project E:\Work\XXX\binary\XXX.exe faulted with message: 'access violation at 0x00678827: write of address 0x00030a38'. Process Stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.

this happens whenever I try to set the value of a field in the clientdataset(I'm using it as a in-memory dataset) as so:

```
with ADataModule do begin
  cdsTest.Append;
  cdsTestAField.AsString := ATableField.AsString;
  // ...
end;
```

both fields are TStringField, cdsTestAField has size 64 and ATableField has size 32

Note: that I'm calling the CreateDataSet method before anything else, also this happens only with the string fields, any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Be careful using `with`; when `ADataModule` does not include `cdsTest`, but your current scope does, then you can get yourself in deep trouble.

Comment: thank you for the heads up Jeroen, but I always keep non-visual components on the datamodule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And where does ATableField come from? Could it be that it is an invalid reference to an object that is already freed?

Also, you can include midaslib.pas in your project to eliminate the use of an external midaslib.dll. It will make your project slightly larger, though, because you are basically compiling the dll in you exe.

Comment: @GolezTrol ATableField is NOT freed, it's created and freed by the datamodule. The length of the string in ATableField is 11 characters or 22 bytes(CTRL+F7) to see the data, yes you need to add ADataModule.ATableField.AsString in order to see the value.

Comment: Well, it's hard to find the cause of an access violation. If all the objects in your code exist and are valid, the code is ok and should work fine. As far as I know, you don't need ShareMem to work with string fields in a ClientDataset when using a separate midas.dll, but you could try that by including either ShareMem or MidasLib in your project. If that is not the case, the error must be in another part of your code.

Comment: the violator comes into play whenever I try to assign a value to a particular TStringField, which is also valid, however something doesn't make sense, all other fields are working properly, it's just this one that doesn't want to comply, weird...

Comment: OK, so I've managed to find the issue, you were right, the issue was in another place: I have an AfterScroll event and in this event I do some stuff and then I have a cxDBLookupComboBox which has assigned OnEditValueChanged(which also tries to set value to the cdsATestField) -- THIS IS the issue, I believe this is a stack overflow :D except that it didn't raised a stack overflow. Thank you very much for your time GolezTrol.

Comment: midaslib.pas is only inluded in the latest versions of Delphi. It's not available for instance, in Delphi 7.

Comment: @Edelcome sorry, I didn't mention the delphi version that I'm using, I use Delphi 2010 and it has midaslib.

Comment: @Edelcom, `midaslib.pas` **is** available on Delphi 7.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund: no it isn't. Not on my Delphi 7 prof installation. But midaslib.dcu is - I honestly never knew it was there. Does this mean you don't have to install midas.dll when you include midaslib.dcu ? I will certainly try that, because midas.dll has given problems in the past (when after your installation a program which used midas.dll too, was installed and uninstalled). Thanks.